# Valore logico di "al computer" nella frase "Sono molto abile negli esercizi al computer"

Tags: grammar

Interrogandomi sull'analisi logica della frase

"Sono molto abile negli esercizi al computer"

mi è sorto un dubbio riguardo al valore logico di "al computer". Penso ad espressioni come "esercizi alle parallele" o "manovre al volante", in cui mi sembra che la stessa struttura entri in gioco. Mi verrebbe da dire che si tratti di complementi di luogo (almeno in origine) di cui la ripetizione in locuzioni piuttosto rigide ha alterato almeno in parte il valore logico in un complemento di mezzo.

Qualcuno può illuminarmi a riguardo?

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Franco!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Credo sia *complemento di limitazione*.

> Il **complemento di limitazione** delimita il campo entro il quale è
>   valido un giudizio o va inteso un predicato. È retto dalle
>   preposizioni **a, da, di, in, per** e dalle locuzioni **in fatto di, a
>   giudizio di, rispetto a, a parere di, riguardo a**, e simili: ad
>   esempio, *bravo in matematica, generoso a parole, cieco di un occhio,
>   stare male a quattrini, sordo da un orecchio, indegno di perdono,
>   degno di considerazione, lodevole per il suo impegno, a mio parere sei
>   forbito nel linguaggio, riguardo alla forma il componimento è buono,
>   quel giocatore è abile nel dribbling*.

http://grammatica-italiana.dossier.net/grammatica-italiana-05.htm

Come nota personale, ho sempre trovato l'esercizio "indovina il nome del complemento" piuttosto inutile. Almeno a me, la conoscenza dei nomi dei quaranta e passa complementi (e ce ne sono di davvero fantasiosi!) non ha mai aiutato. Per dire, su un sito Internet ho trovato questo:

> Il **complemento di stima** indica il grado, la misura della stima che si
>   attribuisce ad una persona o ad un avvenimento ("Stimo moltissimo
>   quelli che lottano contro la droga").

Comment: Sì, concordo, avevo dimenticato l'esistenza del complemento di limitazione..concordo con la nota personale, con l'eccezione di quando serve tradurre.

Comment: Come accenna @Franco, l'utilità maggiore della distinzione dei complementi è per riconoscere certe funzioni logiche in altre lingue (e soprattutto come preliminare per lo studio del latino: altrimenti non avrebbero senso distinzioni apparentemente fini a sé stesse come quella tra il complemento di agente e quello di causa efficiente, se non fosse che in latino si esprimono in due modi diversi).

Comment: Sarei curioso di sapere per quale altra lingua viva la grammatica preveda la categorizzazione dei complementi come in italiano.

Answer (score 2):

Forse *"negli esercizi al computer"* è complemento di limitazione, mentre *"al computer"* a sé è complemento di luogo, in quanto specifica il contesto della limitazione. 
Sottinteso *"Sono molto abile negli esercizi (**svolti**, **che si svolgono**) al computer"*.